# OSError: [E053] Could not read config file from C:\Users\

Tags: spacy

I am trying to run nlp = en_core_web_sm.load(). But getting below error continuously
OSError: [E053] Could not read config file from C:\Users\xxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm\en_core_web_sm-2.3.1\config.cfg

I have checked solution for similar issue (https://github.com/OmkarPathak/pyresparser/issues/46) and followed below steps:
pip install nltk
pip install spacy==2.3.5
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1.tar.gz
pip install pyresparser

Still I am getting same error.

I am using spaCy version 2.3.5 and en_core_web_sm version 2.3.1

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the way you would install the spaCy model and use it is like this.

First in the shell:

```
pip install spacy==2.3.5
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Then in Python:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

I am not exactly sure what is causing your particular error - maybe because you are using `pip install` with a URL directly something is getting set up oddly? It is also possible you are getting weird interactions between conda and pip.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you can accept it by clicking the check mark (✔) to the left of it.

Comment: Getting [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\shraddha.shetty\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\~hinc\\backends\\cblas.cp39-win_amd64.pyd' while trying to install pip .can you tell me how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

For Spacy 2.3.5 version and to have it worked efficiently it is better to follow these steps:

1. Use Python 3.6 to 3.9 version. Check version of python installed

   python -V
2. Use Upgraded pip

   python -m pip install –-upgrade pip
3. Install wheel

   pip install -U wheel
4. Install spacy

   pip install -U spacy==2.3.5
5. Download en_core_web_sm

   python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
6. Then in python

   import spacy
   nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

Answer (score 0):

you can write `!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`
before loading model like

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
 
NER = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["tok2vec", "tagger", "parser", "attribute_ruler", "lemmatizer"])
```

It works for me in Jupyter Notebook with python3